# Reading files in PGDATA and security concerns.

Tags: database, postgresql, filesystems

The POSTGRES database file layout is very well documented in [its manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/storage-file-layout.html). However, I am still unsure about the content of the files themselves from a security perspective.

My question is if someone were to get access to the table files located in `PGDATA/base/db_OID/table_filenode` would they be able to read the contents of the database without the need of logging into the database?

I have noticed that those files are stored in binary format since I can't read it with `cat` (you get only gibberish). However, it is not clear to me whether someone with the appropriate tools would be able to read those files without the database's passwords. Or even if they had the database's passwords, would they be able to read it?

Any help in clarifying this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: This is pretty obvious. That's why you need correct permissions for the directory.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @Tometzky, however it doesn't answer the question. My question is were somebody to access that folder (for instance the system admin, an intruder, etc), could they read the files in there? Of course, directory permissions are important.